# Need a way to copy a file to Livelink from a cmd prompt (a la davcopy)

Tags: livelink

Has anyone written something like davcopy for Livelink? (davcopy works with SharePoint)

I have downloaded davcopy and it hangs when trying to use it with Livelink.

I've asked Open Text and their response is "There is not way to do this out of the box, it will requires writing a webservices application."

I'm not sure how to write a webservice application for livelink; so, before I explore that I was wondering if anyone had done an implementation of davcopy for Livelink.

Answer (score 0):

I know about a command line application which is using MS powershell to do what you want (http://www.gatevillage.net/public/content-server-desktop-library-powershell-suite)
It wouldn't be too difficult to write something like this with Ruby or Perl. Both support WS/SOAP.
With which version of Livelink (or Content Server) do you work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**`curl`**](https://curl.haxx.se/) command line tool to upload, download or delete files in Livelink.  It makes HTTP requests against CS REST API, which is available in CS 10.0 or newer.

For example, uploading a file "file.ext" to folder 8372 at http://server/instance/cs as Admin:

```
curl \
  -F "type=144" \
  -F "parent_id=8372" \
  -F "name=file.ext" \
  -F "file=@/path/to/file.ext" \
  -u "Admin:password" \
  -H "Expect:" \
  http://server/instance/cs/api/v1/nodes
```

The "Expect" header has to be forced empty, because CS REST API does not support [persistent connections](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html), but `curl` would always enable them for this request.